# .NET Web Browser Control Emulation on Windows 10

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I have made a personal app using VB. The app uses Webbrowser control to load modern site so I edited my registry to have my app use Windows 8.1 IE browser instead of ActiveX browser built in with VB.

The registry edit I made was,

> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]
>   "APPLICATION.exe"=dword:00000000

This worked fine with the application until I upgrade it to Windows 10. Now the application won't load the browser if I have the key and when I delete it, it uses the default ActiveX control which doesn't support many things. Is there any way to make it work ? IE is still there on Windows 10 but I am guessing Edge is the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dword value should be 11000 in decimal, so the WebBrowser control displays the Web page like the Internet Explorer 11.

Add the same dword inside

> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet
>   Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_NATIVE_DOCUMENT_MODE]

to be sure it works properly.

Comment: thanks :) I did try 9000 before and it din't work.. but this somehow worked :D